# Jade -- how can i get a value from id

Tags: javascript, pug

in jade file

```
h1 #score
```

from above content, it displays value 65. Namely, I can get the value 65 from id score.

Now how can I get value from #score?

I tried

```
var = document.getElementById("score").text();
```

but it shows error : Cannot read property 'getElementById' of undefined

Comment: There is a bug above. It should display "in jade file,  h1 #score"

Comment: So where do you run that code?

Comment: `var = ` is incorrect.  you need an identifier.  `var WHAT = `. not sure that'll fix your `document` problem though.

Comment: @sircapsalot it definitely would not: the provided code throws parsing error (expectedly), which means OP shows us something irrelevant.

Comment: Sorry I forget adding the identifier. I write the code in a.jade file. In the file , I I write var n = document.getElementById("score").innerText();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jade files are compiled by JavaScript (Yes, there are some other compilers written in other languages as well). Since Jade files are usually compiled on server or in a building environment, you can't directly use DOM APIs in these files that way.

You should wrap your code with a `script` tag, so the script is executed on the browser and not during the compiling process. "Cannot read property `'getElementById'` of `undefined`" means that you are using DOM APIs directly in your Jade files and these APIs do not exist in that environment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I get why I cannot use getElementById in Jade file now.

Comment: How I can get the value in the jade file then ?

Comment: As Jade allows you to use JavaScript directly in a template file, you can define a variable and use it wherever you want. `- var n = 65` and then  `h1 #score= n`.